# Omnifaces Taglib not found within EL in CustomComponent

Tags: jsf, jboss, wildfly, el, omnifaces

I am currently upgrading a webapp from JBoss 7.1 to Wildfly 10.1, where I stumbled over a rather tricky problem concerning taglib resolution within an expression language within a custom component.

I managed to isolate the problem, which apparently boils down to the fact, that JSFs ExpressionBuilder cannot find the correct name spaces defined in my custom component and therefore complains that it does not know anything about the Omnifaces taglib:

```
javax.el.ELException: Function 'of:format1' not found
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:275)
at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:172)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:227)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:238)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:295)
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:112)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:53)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(WeldExpressionFactory.java:48)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:53)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(WeldExpressionFactory.java:48)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:411)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:342)
```

Funny enough, that only happens if I inline the evaluation of a nested EL expression within `of:format1`.

A minimal example, where the problem can be reproduced, can be found at a [Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/birnbuazn/eltest/src/), but here's the relevant code of my custom component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

<h:head>
    <title>Testing EL</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="model" type="sandbox.eltest.model.Entity" required="true" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <c:set var="value" value="#{cc.attrs.model.value}" />
            #{of:format1('Hello {0}', value)} <!-- Prints "Hello World" correctly -->
            #{of:format1('Hello {0}', cc.attrs.model.value)} <!-- THROWS javax.el.ELException -->
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</h:body>

</html>
```

The second version with the inlined `cc.attrs.model.value` used to work in JBoss 7.1. What am I missing here on Wildfly 10.1?

Comment: Exception is recognizable as consequence of a Mojarra specific XML namespace bug. Try moving `xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"` into `<cc:implementation>` or perhaps `<div>` to exclude one and other.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue. As far as I see Wildfly comes bundled with a `jsf-impl-2.2.13.SP1.jar`. Would updating that to 2.2.14 resolve the XML namespace bug?

Comment: @BalusC Tried moving the workspaces and updating the `jsf-impl`. Neither of which worked...

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having same problem in mojarra 2.3.3

Comment: Nope, unfortunately we had to change all our EL expressions in this particular project. Things like this are one of the reasons why I’m not so happy with JSF and avoid it wherever I can.